# Android and storage

Tags: android, storage, external, mount, internal

I am trying to find all storage in the Android device. I am currently processing "/proc/mounts" file, but I have problems understanding all the lines. As much as I read on the subject it seems I can not find bulletproof way to handle lines in "proc/mounts".

It seems that mount points can be found in lines that start with "/dev/block/vold/" but also in lines with "/dev/fuse" at the beginning.

However, it seems that some lines with ""/dev/block/vold/"" are not valid, and also some with "/dev/fuse" are not valid, but I can't seem to find a pattern,

Example:
This is /proc/mounts" file from my Nexus (some lines and part of these lines deleted for clarity):

```
/dev/fuse /mnt/shell/emulated fuse 
/dev/fuse /storage/emulated/0 fuse 
/dev/fuse /storage/emulated/legacy fuse
```

In this case it seems only "/storage/emulated/0" points to (internal) sdcard. It seems i can ignore other "/dev/fuse" lines.

On Xperia z2, "mounts" file is like this:

```
/dev/fuse /mnt/shell/emulated fuse
/dev/block/vold/179:65 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 vfat 
/dev/fuse /storage/sdcard1 fuse
/dev/fuse /storage/emulated/0 fuse
/dev/fuse /storage/emulated/legacy fuse
```

In this case it seems I should use "/dev/fuse /storage/emulated/0" and "/storage/sdcard1" but ignore the rest of the lines.

But what are the other lines and how to tell which ones to use?